# Using gdal_translate with a high number of gcp

Tags: gdal, csv, georeferencing, gdal-translate, string

I've a CSV file witch describes the coordinates of each pixels in a image, it is structured like this:

```
xcoord,ycoord,row,col
716657.6518375501,4784215.095395751,0,0
716657.6915582813,4784215.125764541,0,1
716657.7312790118,4784215.156133341,0,2
716657.7312790131,4784215.156133339,0,3
716657.810720475,4784215.216870922,0,4
....
....
716728.6399590928,4784196.171360771,1164,898
716728.6796798228,4784196.201729561,1164,899
```

Now I want to georeference the image using all of this points, I try to do the following script using gdal_translate:

```
def georeferencig (img,tab_coord):
    csvfile = open(tab_coord)   
    tab = csv.DictReader (csvfile, delimiter=',')
    lista = []
    for row in tab:
        string_1 = '-gcp ' + repr(row['row']) + ' ' + repr(row['col']) + ' ' + repr(row['xcoord']) + ' ' + repr(row['ycoord']) + ' '
        lista.append (string_1)
    string = ''
    for part in lista:
        string = string + part
    output_name = img.split('.')[0] + '_refraction.tif'

translate = 'gdal_translate -of GTIFF -a_srs EPSG:32631 ' + string + img + ' ' + output_name 
os.system(translate)
```

If I run this script the system gives me no results or errors, I try to use just a little part of the points writing for example:

```
def georeferencig (img,tab_coord):
    csvfile = open(tab_coord)   
    tab = csv.DictReader (csvfile, delimiter=',')
    lista = []
    for row in tab:
        string_1 = '-gcp ' + repr(row['row']) + ' ' + repr(row['col']) + ' ' + repr(row['xcoord']) + ' ' + repr(row['ycoord']) + ' '
        lista.append (string_1)
    string = ''
    for part in lista:
        string = string + part
    output_name = img.split('.')[0] + '_refraction.tif'
    example = "-gcp '244' '495' '716683.4853030661' '4784220.244624769' -gcp '244' '496' '716683.5250237972' '4784220.274993559' -gcp '244' '497' '716683.5647445283' '4784220.305362349' -gcp '244' '498' '716683.6044652605' '4784220.335731139' -gcp '244' '499' '716683.6441859904' '4784220.36609993' -gcp '244' '500' '716683.6839067215' '4784220.3964687195' "

translate = 'gdal_translate -of GTIFF -a_srs EPSG:32631 ' + example + img + ' ' + output_name 
os.system(translate)
```

And with only this points the script works fine.
Do you think that the problem is the high number of gcp written in 'string' or maybe some part of the script are not correct? 
If I print 'string' I can see that is correct but has more or less 59.000.000 characters.

Comment: There is a test with 2115 gcps in this rather new commit https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/commit/5426fbb5939ec949739e29d63c02930a2e1788a2. However, I have a feeling that there might be some other way to handle your data. Gcp at every pixel is something quite ultimate.

Comment: If your raster data has only one band you could perhaps create a point data set from your CSV with pixel value as an attribute and create a new raster with gdal_grid https://gdal.org/programs/gdal_grid.html.